# React hook submit form after setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Using the new `react hooks`. 
How do you update the state and then submit a form.

Example: I have a search box that uses the normal state with `setSearch` and on submit, it fetches data on the server. 
I also have a `history` of searches, and if the user clicks on that, it should populate the search and then submit the form.

```
const Search = () => {
   const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

   const onSubmit = () =>{
      fetch('http://server.com/?search='+search)...
   }

   const onClickShortcut = (shortcutSearch) =>{
      setSearch(shortcutSearch)
      onSubmit()
   }

   return ...
}
```

When I click on a button with `onClickShortcut`, it launched the `onSubmit` but the search is wrong...is there a callback on setState or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use React's `useEffect` hook to add some kind of callback to state change.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Search = () => {
   const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

   const onSubmit = () =>{
      fetch('http://server.com/?search='+search)...
   }
   useEffect(()=>{ // this will re run every time search changes
      if(search!=='') onSubmit()
   }, [search])

   const onClickShortcut = (shortcutSearch) =>{
      setSearch(shortcutSearch)
   }

   return ...
}
```

Comment: The issue with this, is that if a user types a search, on every keystroke, it would fetch on the server, which could be something people need, but not me.

Answer (score 0):

If no one has a better solution, the only way I found was unbundling the `onSubmit`, see below:

```
const Search = () => {
   const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

   const onSubmit = () =>{
      doSearch(search)
   }

  const doSearch = (searchStr) =>{
    fetch('http://server.com/?search='+searchStr)...
  }

   const onClickShortcut = (shortcutSearch) =>{
      setSearch(shortcutSearch)
      doSearch(shortcutSearch)
   }

   return ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setSearch` is not synchronous and value will be updated after sometime asynchronously

You need `useEffect()` hook to determine if value has changed

```js
const Search = () => {
   const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

   const onSubmit = () =>{
      fetch('http://server.com/?search='+search)...
   }

   const onClickShortcut = (shortcutSearch) =>{
      setSearch(shortcutSearch);
   }
   useEffect(() => {
      // this will trigger when search will get updated
      onSubmit()
   }, [search]);

   return ...
}
```

Comment: The issue with this, is that if a user types a search, on every keystroke, it would fetch on the server, which could be something people need, but not in my case.